# Number of items to Replace is not Multiple of Length

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a poverty status indicator variable based on household income, family size, and a minimum poverty threshold.  However, every time I run the code, I receive the "number of items to replace is not a multiple of length" error message.  A lot of the code may be completely redundant, but I'm relatively new to R and have mostly just tried anything to try to get rid of the error message.

data = the data frame from which my original variables are sourced

```
inc<-vector()
length(inc)<-length(data$BYFAMINC)

inc[data$BYFAMINC=="1"]<-NA
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="2"]<-500
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="3"]<-2000
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="4"]<-4000
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="5"]<-6250
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="6"]<-8750
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="7"]<-12500
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="8"]<-17500
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="9"]<-22500
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="10"]<-30000
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="11"]<-42500
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="12"]<-62500
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="13"]<-87500
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="14"]<-150000
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="15"]<-200000
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="98"]<-NA
inc[data$BYFAMINC=="99"]<-NA

inc<-as.numeric(inc)

table(inc)

data$inc<-inc



fmlysz<-vector()
length(fmlysz)<-length(data$BYFAMSIZ)
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==1]<-1
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==2]<-2
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==3]<-3
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==4]<-4
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==5]<-5
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==6]<-6
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==7]<-7
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==8]<-8
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==9]<-9
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==10]<-10
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==98]<-NA
fmlysz[data$BYFAMSIZ==99]<-NA
fmlysz<-as.numeric(fmlysz)


table(fmlysz)


poverty<-vector()
length(poverty)<length(data$BYFAMSIZ)
poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==2]<-(data$inc/7704)
poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==3]<-(data$inc/9435)
poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==4]<-(data$inc/12092)
poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==5]<-(data$inc/14304)
poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==6]<-(data$inc/16146)
poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==7]<-(data$inc/18232)
poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==8]<-(data$inc/20253)
poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==9]<-(data$inc/24129)
poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==10]<-(data$inc/24129)
poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==98]<-NA
poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==99]<-NA
poverty<-as.numeric(poverty)
table(poverty)
summary(poverty)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: 1) Can you post `dput(head(data$BYFAMINC, 20))` in the question? Without data it's difficult to say what is wrong. 2) Why do you create `fmlysz` if it's not used in the creation of `poverty`?

Comment: Hi, and welcome!  Does the code work right up until the third block (with `poverty`)?  If so, a typo might be to blame: `length(poverty)` **`<`** `length(data$BYFAMSIZ)`.  You left out the `-`, so your intended assignment operator `<-` is actually just a "less than" comparison `<`.  The result is that you never actually change the length of your initially empty `poverty` vector: `length(poverty)<length(data$BYFAMSIZ)` leaves `poverty` with length `0`.

Comment: So when you attempt to overwrite the values in `poverty`, you're trying to replace 0 items in `poverty` with some some _n_ items from `BYFAMSIZ`: `poverty[data$BYFAMSIZ==2]<-(data$inc/7704)`.  Since _n_ is not a multiple of 0, the values in `BYFAMSIZ` cannot be recycled (as a failsafe for mismatching lengths) over the length of `poverty`, so we get the error message: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of length`.